# Command "db:seed" don't work at hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-seeding

Rather works, but it is not accurate. I created many migrations on the local server and debugged them by

`php artisan migrate`

and

`php artisan migrate:reset`.

Everything works, no problem. Next, I created classes to fill the tables in the **seeds** folder. And, consequently, I tested the script for loading data into the database:

`php artisan db:seed`.

Here, too, everything works fine, the site after these tests is displayed as before. Next, I upload all these changes to the hosting. I note that up to this point this project was already on hosting, but I imported the database there using MySQL. And there it was also displayed perfectly. And now I wanted to test the migration and filling the initial data on the host server. All this is done, of course, by SSH. And what is surprising

`php artisan migrate`

and

`php artisan migrate:reset`

work on the hosting correctly, the tables are deleted and created without errors. And when i try to run

`php artisan db:seed`

The first class in the list of the **run()** method of the **DatabaseSeeder** class does not already see the script and I get this error:

`Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist`

And all other classes are also out of range.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: have you checked the `databaseseeder.php`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have an old `autoload` file prior to uploading the new code. Try `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dumpautoload`. If those fail, delete the contents of the `bootstrap/cache` directory and rerun those two commands.